# How can I use gothic font as the initial font?

Tags: fonts

I know

```
\textgt{sometext}
```

gives gothic font.

But I have to only use gothic font, so I do not want to write `\textgt` for every sentence.

So I decided to set inital font as gothic, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you asking about a "lettrine", i.e., an enlarged letter for the very beginning of a paragraph?

Comment: @Mico: I think, it is rather a global font change

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You may well be correct. Let's see if the OP provides some more specific information...

Comment: @Mico: Yes... if he means `lettrine`, you can provide the answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using special font packages this can be done with special commands such as `\gothfamily` or `egothfamily` etc. The precise command depends on the font and the package and if `XeLaTeX/LuaTeX` or `PDFLaTeX` is used.

See [bookhand fonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookhands) for more examples on those kind of fonts.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{egothic}%
\usepackage{pgothic}%
\usepackage{yfonts}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\gothfamily
\blindtext

\egothfamily
\blindtext

\pgothfamily
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my point of view, `\egothfamily` rather provides some Uncials than gothic letters...